# Consolidate union result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am selecting email address from two source tables via a union query. Normally, I would leverage union's behavior of filtering out duplicate values, but in this case, each source table may or may not have a value for each person, and I have to give "priority" to the email address from the first source table when it exists.

When I encounter a situation where the same email address exists in *both* sources, I would like to to omit the line from source 2 where the email matches that from source 1, as shown below. Assuming CURRENT DATA, how can I make a new selection from CURRENT DATA to arrive at DESIRED RESULT?

CURRENT DATA

| PERSONID | EMAILADDRESS | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7538583 | email@example | 1 |
| 7538583 | email@example | 2 |
| 7538583 | person@somecompany | 2 |

DESIRED RESULT

| PERSONID | EMAILADDRESS | SOURCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7538583 | email@example | 1 |
| 7538583 | person@somecompany | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the second part of the union:

```
select personid,
       emailaddress,
       1 as source
  from table1

union

select personid,
       emailaddress,
       2 as source
  from table2
 where not exists (select 1 from table1 where table1.personid = table2.personid);
```

Comment: @BrianBrock . . . It is not quite perfect.  It should use `union all` so it doesn't incur additional overhead for removing duplicates.